# Log4Net Persist buffer when program closes

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, log4net

Brand new to the Log4Net library and there is something I have not been able to figure out.

I assume the buffer is in memory only, right?  And when you start a new instance of your application the buffer is re-initialized?  I have a requirement where I've been told to only send an email to tech support after an application fails x number of times.  This application will be run on a schedule (every two minutes or so).  If it fails, it will just try again in two minutes.  If it fails too many times unsuccessfully (and is failing due to errors being thrown) then it should send the email out.

The easiest way I can think to do this right now is to persist the number of failed attempts to the user.config.  Then, when my program catches an exception check to see how many failed attempts have occurred, and if the threshold is hit then to send an email using the correct logger/appender.  After a successful run of the program, the last thing it would do before exiting would be to reset the user.config setting to 0 failed attempts.

Is there a better way?  Perhaps some way to persist the buffer so that I can do something with the lossy setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer is in memory, which means that if you will launch the application again and again thought schedule task, you will have to persist your data somehow.

i would use a file or the registry for that (others persistent solutions - database, [memcached](http://memcached.org/)... etc)

for sending a message with log4net you can look at [this post](http://sradack.blogspot.co.il/2007/09/have-log4net-send-email-when-error.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So, would you use the different levels to differentiate here: if (numberFailedAttempts >= 3) { logger.Fatal("wired up to email appender"); } else { logger.Error("wired up to other rolling appender"); }  -- Something like that?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to do... you can write a log to a file if numberFailedAttemps < 3 (with info / warning threshold) and write to log file and send email if numberFailedAttempts == 3 (with error threshold)

then you apply email appender to error threshold, and file appender to info / warning